# How to add new json object into json array in node-postgres?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a column named alerts with the type of json[] and I want to add json objects to this array such as {name: alert1, time: 12:00}.

I tried this code but it throws an error (error: malformed array literal: "$1")

```
await pool.query(
"UPDATE datas SET alerts = alerts || '$1' WHERE id = '10'",
[JSON.stringify({ name: "alert1", time: "12:00" })]);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just matter of syntax errors, keys should be between double quotes and also in the call to pool.query parameter $1 doesn't need apostrophes

```
UPDATE datas SET alerts = alerts || ('{"name":"alert1", "time":"12:00"}')::json 
WHERE id = '10';
```

In your code

```
pool.query("UPDATE datas SET alerts = alerts || $1::json WHERE id = '10'", 
[{ "name": "alert1", "time": "12:00" }], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('Error executing query', err.stack)
    }
    console.log(result.rowCount) // rows affected
  })
```

Comment: I changed my code to this  
await pool.query("UPDATE datas SET alerts = alerts || '$1'::json WHERE id = '10'",[JSON.stringify({ "name": "alert1", "time": "12:00" })]);
now it says "error: invalid input syntax for type json" but without ::json it still throws the same error

Comment: You're right, now I corrected and tested successfully.

Comment: hello, it is kinda off topic but what about if I want to replace the array with new array? (so not adding any item this time, I need to replace the array with new array) I tried this but did not work: await pool.query("UPDATE datas SET alerts = '{}'::json[] || $1::json[]",
[JSON.stringify(alerts).replaceAll('[', '{').replaceAll(']', '}')]); this throws an error  => error: malformed array literal: "{{"option":"ns=3;s=\"random_out\"","minOrEqual":"10000","maxOrEqual":"120000","frequencyTime":"100000","lastSendedTime":"2022-10-12T20:49:26.396Z"}}" any idea how to fix this?

Comment: For a new array (not appended), like this `pool.query("UPDATE datas SET alerts = $1::json[] WHERE id = '10'", 
[[{ "name": "alert1 from node", "time": "12:38" }]]` requires another pair of square brackets to express array. But if you want to clear the field is `update datas set alerts =null where id='10'`